# Deploying a Flask application with CGI

Tags: python, flask, cgi

I have written a small application using the Flask framework. I try to host this using cgi. Following the documentation I created a .cgi file with the following content:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from wsgiref.handlers import CGIHandler
from yourapplication import app

CGIHandler().run(app)
```

Running the file results in following error:

...

> File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/werkzeug/routing.py", line 1075, in bind_to_environ
>       wsgi_server_name = environ.get('HTTP_HOST', environ['SERVER_NAME'])
>   KeyError: 'SERVER_NAME'
>   Status: 500 Internal Server Error
>   Content-Type: text/plain
>   Content-Length: 59

In my application I have set:

```
app.config['SERVER_NAME'] = 'localhost:5000'
```

When I run the application with the Flask development server it works perfectly well. 
As you can tell I'm very new to this stuff and I have search for others with similar errors but with no luck. All help is appreciated.

Comment: Do you run it under some http server ? Those environment vars should be set by the http server executing the cgi.

Comment: Thanks for the comment.I'm running apache for hosting. I didn't think I needed to configure the server just to run the commands locally. I will try again after I have made the configurations needed.

Comment: This question is three years old, and was never flagged as answered. If you're looking for a pretty complete discussion of how to do it see the most recent post, by me, to [this related stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18259435/deploy-flask-application-on-11-shared-hosting-with-cgi). It should work for you. Certainly mkriheli has the right idea; monostop should not be trying to run the cgi file (let the server do that in response to an incoming HTTP request).

Comment: Indeed, http://stackoverflow.com/a/24848407/2371522 worked for me.

Comment: Did you able to fix this error ?

Answer (score 3):

I will try to show what I've done and it is working in Godaddy sharing host account:

In the cgi-bin folder in MYSITE folder, I added the following cgi file:

```
#!/home/USERNAME/.local/bin/python3
from wsgiref.handlers import CGIHandler

from sys import path
path.insert(0, '/home/USERNAME/public_html/MYSITE/')
from __init__ import app

class ProxyFix(object):
   def __init__(self, app):
       self.app = app

   def __call__(self, environ, start_response):
       environ['SERVER_NAME'] = ""
       environ['SERVER_PORT'] = "80"
       environ['REQUEST_METHOD'] = "GET"
       environ['SCRIPT_NAME'] = ""
       environ['QUERY_STRING'] = ""
       environ['SERVER_PROTOCOL'] = "HTTP/1.1"
       return self.app(environ, start_response)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.wsgi_app = ProxyFix(app.wsgi_app)
    CGIHandler().run(app)
```

As you can see the **init** file in the MYSITE folder have the flask app.

The most important thing is to set the permissions right. I setted 755 to this folder permission AS WELL AS to "/home/USERNAME/.local/bin/python3" folder!! Remember that the system needs this permission to open flask.

To open the cgi I have the following .htaccess file in MYSITE folder:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /home/USERNAME/public_html/MYSITE/cgi-bin/application.cgi/$1 [L]
```

So it will render the cgi file when someone enters your page.

Comment: This was very helpful for a stupid deployment situation I got into on a shared hosting environment.

Make sure to comment out or remove the PATH_INFO line though, it may interfere with any Flask routes you have defined.

Comment: Edited and removed the PATH_INFO

Comment: Are you meant to retain USERNAME in the RewriteRule or replace that with your account name?

Comment: Replace with your account name

Answer (score 0):

This is posted as an answer following the comments above for the sake of completeness.

As discussed above, cgi scripts should execute by some server. Here's the abstract [from CGI 1.1 RFC](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3875):

> The Common Gateway Interface (CGI) is a simple interface for running
>   external programs, software or gateways under an information server in
>   a platform-independent manner.  Currently, the supported information
>   servers are HTTP servers.

For the environment variables (which were missing and triggered the error) see sectuib 4.1 in the RFC.