# Deploying Flask Rest API using Shared Hosting

Tags: python, api, rest, flask

I'm having trouble deploying my REST API and keep getting a 500 Internal Server Error. I've gone through several possible solutions and guides to fix this problem, including those below:

http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/deploying/cgi/

[Deploy flask application on 1&1 shared hosting (with CGI)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18259435/deploy-flask-application-on-11-shared-hosting-with-cgi)

and was following this guide:

http://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/designing-a-restful-api-with-python-and-flask

Here is my code:

restapplication.py

```
#!/home/myusername/public_html/todo-api/flask/bin/python
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return "Hello, World!"
```

run.cgi

```
#!/home/myusername/public_html/todo-api/flask/bin/python

import cgitb; cgitb.enable()
from wsgiref.handlers import CGIHandler
from restapplication import app

CGIHandler().run(app)
```

.htaccess (stored at /home/myusername/public_html/)

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /home/myusername/public_html/todo-api/flask/run.cgi/$1            [L]
```

I appreciate all the help I can get.

Comment: I assume your `return` is actually indented...

Comment: what do you find in your apache (error) logs?

Comment: In my python file, it is indented properly.

Comment: Under the log section, in cpanel, the Error Log is empty.

Comment: Try creating a super simple script that just echoes - like [this one](https://gist.github.com/waynew/3db08ae053b9e9940ae5)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you got the solution, but for records-

if you have your virtual environment set, then you will have to add these lines in your `restapplication.py` to point to the `site-packages`, so that your code can access `Flask` library.

```
import os
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, '/home/username/public_html/cgi-bin/myenv/lib/python2.6/site-packages')
```

Rest everything looks okay.

Maybe you can check the file permissions of the `.cgi` file and `.py` file. The file permissions should be **755**.

refer : http://www.comfycoder.com/home/how_to_deploy_a_flask_app_in_apache_shared_hosting