# is it possible to call a python script from a bash CGI script?

Tags: python, bash, cgi

For example, I have a `hello.sh` CGI bash script, i want to do something like this in the script:

```
m=$(python pythonscript.py)
echo $m
```

I have tried but `m` was blank after `echo`

Comment: There are all kinds of things that could be wrong.  For one `python` might not be in your web server's `PATH`. If `python` happens to be in the `PATH` the `pythonscript.py` file might not be where your web server is looking for it.  Also it could be that `python pythonscript.py` is not returning any output.

Comment: Thanks @RedCricket. I have fixed the PATH for python, what environment variable can I fix for pythonscript.py so webserver can see it?

Comment: In my own shared-hosting experience I can run a Python script directly via CGI. You might like to take a look at my post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18259435/deploy-flask-application-on-11-shared-hosting-with-cgi/24848407#24848407), especially the cgiappserver-prod.cgi file. Note that it's entirely in Python even though it has the .cgi extension. You may find the first line, about the CGI error reporting, to be useful.

Comment: That depends on the web server you are using.  I only know how to configure apache.  If you are using apache the `pythonscript.py` would need to be in the `DocumentRoot` directory.  You could avoid having to worry about the `DocumentRoot` by specifying the full path to `pythonscript.py` … something like `$(python /user/me/my_python_scripts/pythonscript.py)`

Comment: Note placing a script in the DocumentRoot would be a security issue as the text of the script could be visible to the end user.  Please consider what Mike suggested as that would be more secure.

Comment: my context is a bit different, no other way but to mix bash and python back and forth in a bit hacky way... :) but thanks you two, I have finally configured the environment correctly

Answer (score 0):

put this in the bash CGI script

```
PATH=$PATH:<path-to-python-interpreter>
export PATH
```

works finally !